# Run python script from Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I have problem with my Dockerfile.
I want to execute my python script during image building (this script creates a few files).
But this script is not execute during image building - there aren't file created by script in container.

It's my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN python script1.py
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to interact with files during image building, you must add those files to the image first, otherwise how is Docker to know where those files are?

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ADD script1.py /tmp/script1.py
RUN python /tmp/script1.py
```

Of course, I'll leave the paths to you.

Answer (score 0):

FROM ubuntu:latest 
ADD script1.py /tmp/script1.py #add/copy files from some path 
CMD ["python", "/tmp/script1.py"] # to run python with provided script/argument